# Auto download external assemblies when opening solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Here is the situation:
We have source control based on tfs2010, visual studio 2010 and solution which contain projects and have referances to External assemblies. If we open solution and try to build it it will show us error which tell that some assemblies couldn't be find, to make it work we should go in source control explorer find external assembly directory and get latest version, then solution will be build without any errors. Does anybody know how to make solution to autodownload those external assemblies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, create a logical folder (called "External Assemblies") then add the assemblies, by right clicking on the folder then "add existing item...".

Like that:

[image]

This way when you'll load the solution the files will be retrieved from the Source Control (your solution must be bind to the Source Control, of course).